# shellcheck vs. Docker

Tags: bash, docker

Until now I used to stop all running Docker containers like this:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
```

Now that I've used [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), it told me this:

```
Quote this to prevent word splitting.shellcheck(SC2046)
```

So I came up with this:

```bsh
docker stop "$(docker ps -q)"
```

When executing this, I get

```
Error response from daemon: 404 page not found
```

Now I tried `echo "$(docker ps -q)"` which results in

```
f52fe2dfaf9c
c790ee0dc828
a7a5a8c158fd
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update:

The output for `docker stop $(docker ps -q)` is

```
f52fe2dfaf9c
c790ee0dc828
a7a5a8c158fd
```

Comment: Do you have an output for *docker stop $(docker ps -q)*?

Comment: In this case, you need to omit the quotes because you *want* word-splitting to occur.

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the extremely rare cases where you might want word splitting. A more explicit way to do that is to read the input into an *array:*

```bsh
IFS=' ' read -a container_ids -r <<< "$(docker ps -q)"
docker stop "${container_ids[@]}"
```